# Parallel resistor algorithm

Tags: resistors, algorithm

I have build a circuit that functions as a variable load. It consists of 4 resistors in parallel - let's call them R<sub>1</sub>,R<sub>2</sub>,R<sub>3</sub>,R<sub>4</sub> - each with an activation switch (implemeted with a transistor). R<sub>1</sub> has the lowest value, the other resistors have value: R<sub>n</sub> = R<sub>1</sub>*2<sup>n-1</sup>.
I'm currently trying to find an algorithm that calculates the nearest resistance that is above a desired value, R<sub>des</sub>. Does anybody have an idea of how this could be implemented, without looping through all the possible values?

Comment: Okay, i found an even better, very simple, solution. Just take the LSB (highest R value = \$R_4 = R_1\cdot{}2^3\$) and divide the desired resistance, \$R_{des}\$ and use the floor function: 
\$floor(\frac{LSB}{R_{des}}\$) and you have the desired bit pattern that should be switched on.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? (1) If the resistors are in parallel you'll get an inverse decay curve. If they're in series you will get a linear rising resistance with your binary pattern. Are you sure you want parallel? (2) The floor() function can't return any values less than 1 so that rules out any combination involving the '1' resistor.

Comment: (1) part of the reason for choosing parallel, is to be able to handle a larger load. Each (power) resistor takes part of the current (in series they'd all have to take the full current). Furthermore, in my case, linearity is not so important.

Comment: (2) you should note that with the solution suggested in my comment, the resistance will always guarantee a resistance \$\geq\$ the desired resistance. Also, note that what floor function returns in this case is the _bit pattern_ of the activated resistor values. So if i want the highest resistance, i.e., the value of the LSB, i would plug in \$R_{des}=R_{LSB}\$ and get \$floor(\frac{R_{LSB}}{R_{LSB}})=1\$, that is, in the case of 4 resistors, the value of \$R_4\$. Does that it make sense?

Comment: I should add, that what i meant by LSB in my first comment is \$R_{LSB}\$

Comment: So if your resistor ratios are 1, 2, 4 and 8 then \$ R_{LSB}\$ = 8. If you now want a resistance of 'X' you use \$ floor (\frac {R_{LSB}}{X}) = floor (\frac {8}{X})\$ but the only answers you can get from that are 0, 1 and 2 from your 16 possible combinations.

Comment: The floor function can obviously only give integer values. The number of possibilites with 4 resistors should be \$2^4 = 16\$. This is indeed the case. You have to realize that X does not have to be an integer! This indeed gives us all possible values (of course, giving a value that makes the floor value exeed 15 will not be valid). So Say you want X = 0.6. This gives you \$floor(\frac{8}{0.6}) = 13\$ which in binary is 1101; the right combination. @Transistor , i hope that answers your question?

Comment: To anybody who might be interested in why this works, I'll just note it here. Transform all the resistance values to conductance, \$g_n=\frac{1}{R_n}\$, and note that \$g_n = g_{lsb}\dot{}2^{n-1}\$, now the equivalent conductance is: \$g_{eq}=g_1+g_2...g_4=g_1\dot{}2^0+g_1\dot{}2^1+...+g_1\dot{}2^3=g_1\dot{}(2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3)\$ The very last term is exactly the bit pattern we seek, let us call that x. Solving for this: \$g_{eq}=g_1\dot{} x \Leftrightarrow{} x = \frac{g_{eq}}{g_1} = \frac{R_1}{R_{eq}}\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody have an idea of how this could be implemented, without
>   looping through all the possible values?

It's called [successive approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_approximation_ADC) and is used quite effectively in determining the digital value of an analogue signal. So, with 4 resistors you would make 4 decisions in order to decide which of the 15 values above zero was most appropriate: -

[image]

To make this work like an ADC, feed the unknown resistor with a constant current and do the same for the controllable resistance. Then feed both signals to a comparator that "makes the decision".

Alternatively, buy a cheap ADC and throw away your transistor and resistor network in favour of a much more stable R-2R network and inbuilt algorithm.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Actually i wanted to implement it in a uController, but this idea translates well. Thanks! Btw, the reason for not using a DAC is that the transistors/resistors are chosen to be able to handle quite large powers, which is not something ADCs are capable of, to the best of my knowledge.